# Angular Velocity in the Plane of a Lamina

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

A rigid body (i.e., a 2-dimensional object) has principal moments of inertia about the centre of mass of $I_1 = (\mu^2 -1), I_2 = \mu^2 + 1, I_3 = 2\mu^2.$ I wish to show, using the Euler equations, that, in the body fixed frame, the component of angular velocity in the plane of the lamina (i.e., $\sqrt{\Omega_1^2 + \Omega_2^2}$) is constant in time. Using these Euler angle formulae, I get the following:

- $I_1\dot{\Omega}_1 + (I_3 - I_2) \Omega_2 \Omega_3 = 0 \Rightarrow \mu^2 = 1 \text{ or }\dot{\Omega}_1 = - \Omega_2 \Omega_3$
- $ I_2 \dot{\Omega}_2 + (I_1 - I_3) \Omega_3 \Omega_1 = 0 \Rightarrow \dot{\Omega}_2  = \Omega_1 \Omega_3$
- $I_3 \dot{\Omega}_3 + (I_2 - I_1) \Omega_1 \Omega_2 = 0 \Rightarrow \dot{\Omega}_3 = - \frac{1}{\mu^2} \Omega_1 \Omega_2$.

In the case where $\dot{\Omega}_1 = - \Omega_2 \Omega_3$, I am easily able to show that $\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\Omega_1^2 + \Omega_2^2} =0$. In the case where $\mu^2 = 1$, $I_1 = 0, I_2 = I_3 = 2$, so I essentially have a line on the $\hat{x}_1$ axis. But how do I proceed with this case to show that the angular velocity in the plane of the lamina is constant? Can I take $\Omega_1 = 0$ since $I_1 = 0$?

Comment: A 2D planar body has moments of inertia in all three directions.

Comment: I guess you mean a thin body like a sheet.

Comment: Yes, like arbitrarily thin body, extended in the xy plane.

Comment: So $I_3 = I_1 + I_2$ due to the perpendicular axis theorem.